# Is it true that $u + v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, and $u, v$ be eigenvectors corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$  of $ A$ (that is, $Au = \lambda u$ and $Av = \lambda v$). Is it true that $u + v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I know that an eigenvector can't be the $0$ vector, but an eigenvalue can be $0$, it just means the matrix $A$ is not invertible.

By definition $ Au = \lambda u$, where $u \ne 0$, and $Av = \lambda v$, where $v \ne  0$.  So,  $$Au + Av = \lambda u + \lambda v \implies A(u + v) = \lambda (u + v)$$
where $u + v \ne 0$?

I feel like I'm missing something because my solution was too straightforward.

Comment: It is that straight forward as the set of eigenvectors of the same eigenvalue (together with the zero vector) form a subspace called the eigenspace for that eigenvalue where every non zero vector has the same eigenvalue.

Comment: $u$ can be $-v$, but in any other case it's true

Comment: I reformatted the post. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 5):

Well, the set of all eigenvectors of an eigenvalue forms a subspace.

I.e. if u,v $\in Eig(A,\lambda)$ then $a_1 u$+$a_2v\in Eig(A,\lambda)$:

For $Av=\lambda v$ and $Au=\lambda u$ we have:

$A(a_1u+a_2v)=a_1Au+a_2Av=a_1\lambda u+a_2\lambda v=\lambda(a_1u+a_2v)$

**Note:** $0$ is **not** an eigenvector. So the set above is only a space if we add $0$ to the space.

Comment: The set of such eigenvectors only forms a subspace if you allow the zero-vector as an eigenvector.

Comment: true. I will add it above